# REGEXP_REPLACE SQL/ORACLE

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, plsql

Buenas estoy tratando de reemplazar ciertos caracteres de una cadena perteneciente de un campo en mi base de datos. 352-6325632 Reemplazada seria (352)-632-5632 
al utilizar la funcion regexp_replace de oracle el segundo parametro siempre es igual a la salida esperada. Como podria hacer la siguiente expresion 
(352)-632-5632

```
  SELECT EMPLEADO.CODIGO Codigo,EMPLEADO.APELLIDO || ',' || 
   EMPLEADO.NOMBRE "Nombres",
    REGEXP_REPLACE(CLIENTE.TELEFONO, '^\d{3}-\d{7}$','')  
 "REGEXP_REPLACE",CLIENTE.TELEFONO
   FROM EMPLEADO JOIN CLIENTE ON(EMPLEADO.CODIGO = 
  CLIENTE.CODIGO_REP_VENTAS) WHERE LENGTH(CLIENTE.TELEFONO)=11;
```

Answer (score 2):

Remplazando el campo `CLIENTE.TELEFONO` por el dato de ejemplo `352-6325632` tendrías la expresión:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('352-6325632', '^\d{3}-\d{7}$','') FROM DUAL
```

y como en la cadena de remplazos no tienes nada entonces te remplaza el patrón por nada.

Usa los paréntesis para agrupar y almacenar la expresión `()` y \1 para llamarlos, al incluirlos quedaría así:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('352-6325632', '^(\d{3})-(\d{7})$', '(\1)-\2') FROM DUAL
```

> (352)-6325632

Finalmente ajustas la expresión y la cadena de remplazo de acuerdo a tu necesidad

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('352-6325632', '^(\d{3})-(\d{3})(\d{4})$', '(\1)-\2-\3') FROM DUAL
```

> (352)-632-5632

También lo lograrías con:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('352-6325632', '^(.*)-(\d{3})(.*)$', '(\1)-\2-\3')  FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa la siguiente expresión en la consulta SELECT:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE (CLIENTE.TELEFONO, 
                '([[:digit]]{3})-([[:digit]]{3})([[:digit]]{4})', 
                '(\1)-\2-\3')
```

En el segúndo parámetro de REGEXP_REPLACE debes indicar la expresión regular que buscas, y en el tercer parámetro debes indicar el formato de salida.
Los paréntesis en el segundo parámetro se usan para agrupar el resultado de la expresión regular, los cuales se usarán en el tercer parámetro como \1, \2, \3, etc..

Para más información consulta la siguiente [web](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm).